# `yarn link` not updating browser source code

Tags: reactjs, node-modules, yarnpkg, storybook

I have a react app where I am using storybook as a npm package. For the app, I had to modify the package locally, and now I want to use this updated package in my react application.

I used `yarn link` to the package directory.

```
yarn link
```

```
yarn link v1.22.19
success Registered "@project/long-bow".
info You can now run `yarn link "@project/long-bow"` in the projects where you want to use this package and it will be used instead.
```

And in my react application I used

```
yarn link @project/long-bow
```

```
yarn link v1.22.19
success Using linked package for "project/long-bow".
Done in 0.14s.
```

It updates my node_modules in my editor. But if I go to Chrome sources, it displays non-updated source files.

I used `yarn cache clean` but didn't change a thing.